# Why is there an unexpected end of file error in my mysql search project?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to put together a search bar for my database using php, and I have encountered this problem, even though all of my brackets are closed. 
This is my form page:

```
<?php
  require_once('connect.php');
  ?>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="search.php" method="post">
    <label>
      Search
      <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for members"    autocomplete="off">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value=">>" />
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

And this is my php code for search.php

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php');
$output = '';
if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
  $searchq = $_POST['search'];
  $searchq = preg_replace("#[^a-z]#i", "", $searchq);

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM newclient WHERE first_name LIKE '%$searchq%' OR last_name LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die("Could not search!");
  $count = mysql_num_rows($query) ;

  if ($count == 0) {
    $output = "There was no search result!";
      }
    else{
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
          $fname = $row['firstname'];
          $lname = $row['lastname'];
          $id = $row['id'];

          $output .= '<div>'.$fname.' '.$lname.'</div>';
      }
    }

print("$output");
?>
```

Comment: if(isset($_POST['search'])) { is not cloed before the print()

Comment: Because you have a missing `}`